# What would be a proper way to end a .Net app?

Tags: vb.net

I have an app I'm working on and I've given the user a button with the option to close the app at any time - but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it so I'm asking for some feedback just to double check.

Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub CloseButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click
    End
End Sub
```

For all I know this could be a really bad way to achieve this.  Please be gentle!

Comment: Use `Application.Exit` this will fire all the Form Closing events; `End` and `Environment.Exit` do not.  (of course you can also just close the mainform if using the App framework).

Comment: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wt87xba.aspx) goes over the `End` keyword and gives a few reasons why you should try to avoid using it alone.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to close/dispose all the objects you have been instantiating.

Then you can close your application. And to do so, it is better to use `Application.Exit Method`.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(v=vs.110).aspx), *It should informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.*

```
Private Sub CloseButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click

    Application.Exit

End Sub
```